# Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: django, cors

I have backend on Django 4  and frontend on Angular.
Django  started on 192.168.1.195:8080. Angular on the 192.168.1.195:4200

When i try  to open http://192.168.1.195:4200 i got

```
Home:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.195:8080/api/hosts_groups' from origin 'http://192.168.1.195:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field pragma is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

***settings.py***

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.195','127.0.0.1','localhost']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'host_manager.apps.HostManagerConfig',
     # CORS
    'corsheaders',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = (
    "http://192.168.1.195:4200",
    'http://127.0.0.1:4200',
    'http://localhost:4200'
    )

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://192.168.1.195:8080',
    'http://192.168.1.195:4200',
    'http://127.0.0.1:4200',
    'http://localhost:4200',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
    'http://localhost:8080'
    )

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'
        )

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # CORS
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: Have you read the error message? Your client evidently includes a header named `pragma` in the request, and you need to allow that header name in your CORS configuration (by listing `'pragma'` in `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS`). Note that `Pragma` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Pragma), though; you may want to use a more modern alternative.

Comment: Incidentally, you can remove all those `Access-Control-Allow-...` names from `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS`, since those are response headers, not request headers.

Comment: Always read the error message carefully 